# What is our policy on republishing “our“ content to another site?

Tags: discussion

Saw a link to Reddit..

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/11/how-are-robots-beating-my-captchas/

This lead me to : http://arstechnica.com/author/stack-exchange/

It kind of bugged me a bit, that this can be done without even notifying the original author.

What bugs me is that here on SE I can modify my answer at anytime, but once its on arstechnica.com I loose control of it.

Don't get me wrong I really could care less if "my" content is re-posted everywhere because I maintain anonymity. So no harm *can* be done to my professional reputation. But many others do not...

I know that once something is published on SE, it's basically community owned, but this seems to transfer the ownership away from the community.

So the question is "What is our policy on republishing “our“ content to another site?" Who has the authority to authorize this? Can I For example create a Blog "Moron's Favorite Questions"? I know i am allowed to if they are "my" answers, but can if they are someone else?

Can I group a bunch of question on a similar topic and publish a Book and sell it for provide as a free e-book? (arstechnica.com clearly has ads on its site as well as on the specific page reprinting SE data.)

**Where is the line drawn?**

Comment: Incidentally, ars technica goes above and beyond the requirements and uses referral links that give badge credit for the authors of the posts they copy.  They are probably the largest source of publicist badges on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All content on Stack Exchange is licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Anyone can share or remix the content (including for commercial use), as long as you provide proper attribution and share under the same or similar license. [Proper attribution is defined](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) as visually indicating the source site, providing a hyperlink to the original question, identifying the author name for every question and answer used, and hyperlinking from the author's name to the author's profile. I would say that for non-hypertext documents, providing the full URL is the same as hyperlinking.

In short, yes, you can create a list of your favorite questions (including answers posted by you and others) or publish a book (even commercially, as long as it's available under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license) or publish to a website (with or without advertising) as long as you follow the rules of attribution. Ars Technica does follow those rules, so it's fine.